# Equality between volume and surface

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, hausdorff-measure

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1]$. Does there exist some relation between the volume $|\{u > t\}|$ ($|\cdot|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure) and the surface $H^{n-1}(u = s)$, possibly in integral form?

EDIT: I had this question after learning the isoperimetric inequality since it seems that there should be some sort of equality between the volume and surface and not just an inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The isoperimetric inequality: for $V\subset\Bbb R^n$, the measures of the body and the hypersurface verify
$$m_{n-1}(\partial V)\ge n\,m_n(V)^{(n-1)/n}m_n(B_1)^{1/n}$$
with $B_1$ the unit ball.

Interesting integrals-related fact:

> The $n$-dimensional isoperimetric inequality is equivalent (for sufficiently smooth domains) to the Sobolev inequality on $\Bbb R^n$ with optimal constant.

See [Isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)

EDIT: the [coarea formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257042/proof-of-coarea-formula) gives a relation between the measure of a body composed of level sets and the measures of the level sets.
$$
\operatorname{Vol}(M) = \int_M d\operatorname{Vol}_M =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{|\nabla f|}\operatorname{area}(f^{-1}(t))\,dt
$$
(copypaste from the link, you can translate easily the notation)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I was hoping for an equality between the two, as I had this question after finding about the isoperimetric inequality. I probably should've mentioned that in my question.